# Lua inner function vs module-level function

Tags: lua

For a function inside another function, does Lua "instantiate" the inner function on each call to the outer function? If so, would `bar()` in the code below perform worse than `foo()`?

```
local function a()
  print 'a'
end

function foo()
  a()
end

function bar()
  function b()
    print 'b'
  end

  b()
end
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Test case 1: `a` and `b` both global, no embedding.

```
$ cat junk.lua ; time lua junk.lua
function a(n)
    return n + 1
end

function b(n)
    return a(n)
end

for c = 1, 10000000 do
    b(c)
end


real    0m1.743s
user    0m1.740s
sys 0m0.000s
```

User time: **1.74s**.

## Test case 2: `a` local, `b` global, no embedding.

```
local function a(n)
    return n + 1
end

function b(n)
    return a(n)
end

for c = 1, 10000000 do
    b(c)
end


real    0m1.388s
user    0m1.390s
sys 0m0.000s
```

User time **1.39s**.

## Test case 3: `a` and `b` both local, no embedding.

```
$ cat junk.lua ; time lua junk.lua
local function a(n)
    return n + 1
end

local function b(n)
    return a(n)
end

for c = 1, 10000000 do
    b(c)
end


real    0m1.194s
user    0m1.200s
sys 0m0.000s
```

User time **1.2s**.

## Test case 4: `a` embedded in `b`, `a` global, `b` local.

```
$ cat junk.lua ; time lua junk.lua
local function b(n)
    function a(n)
        return n + 1
    end

    return a(n)
end

for c = 1, 10000000 do
    b(c)
end


real    0m2.804s
user    0m2.790s
sys 0m0.000s
```

User time: **2.79s**.  (!)

## Test case 5: `a` embedded in `b`, both local.

```
$ cat junk.lua ; time lua junk.lua
local function b(n)
    local function a(n)
        return n + 1
    end

    return a(n)
end

for c = 1, 10000000 do
    b(c)
end


real    0m2.540s
user    0m2.530s
sys 0m0.000s
```

User time: **2.53s**.

## Result summary:

1. It's easy to write tests to confirm or deny intuitions about performance.  You should probably do this instead of relying on crowd-sourcing the answer.  (The crowd is often wrong, you see.)
2. Making functions local instead of global has a significant positive impact on function call overhead.  (About 30% better in this set of test cases when both functions were local.)
3. Embedding a function in another function has a serious negative impact on function call overhead.  (About 110% worse in this set of test cases when both functions were local.)
4. Did I mention that testing is probably a good idea in lieux of trusting the crowd?

Comment: Thanks! I would've tested, but I wasn't sure how. I guess that should've been my first question.

Answer (score 5):

`bar` will be slower because you are creating a new function object every time. If you want to declare functions inside a function you probably want to return a closure.

```
local bar = function()
  local f = function()
    -- Lots of stuff...
  end
  local g = function()
    -- Also lots of stuff
  end
  return function()
    -- Do something with f and g...
  end
end

local created_f = bar()
created_f()
created_f()  -- Now you can skip the function initialization.
```

Comment: You beat me to it because I did it the long-winded way.  :D  +1

Comment: I actually did a bit of benchmarking to verify a few things, but realized that the original poster probably should do it himself (as you stated in your answer). +1 for you also for a detailed answer.

Comment: I wish I could give you another +1 for the code and showing how to use closures.  (I also wish I'd thought of showing the closure usage myself.)

Answer (score 0):

[Roberto](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/) has written a [pretty comprehensive article](http://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf) on Lua Performance Tips like this.